# Moving Server 2016 Datacentre to new chassis

Tags: windows-server-2016, hyper-v-server-2016

We have a Dell R620 (256GB RAM, 2x3 SSD RAID 10) which has an older tower server as it's manual failover machine. Both are running Server 2016 DataCentre.

Budget for a 2nd Dell R620 with matching specs to the first has been approved.

Paying for a 3rd license of Server 2016 DataCentre is not approved.

I've read conflicting statements on the viability of using a bare metal recovery to move the os with it's license to the new hardware.

**Links stating it can be done:**

https://www.ubackup.com/windows-server/windows-server-backup-bare-metal-recovery-4348.html
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/how-to-restore-windows-installation

Is it at all possible?

Comment: You may want to do a lot more reading. The way I read certain licensing specs you do NOT NEED A LICENSE FOR BACKUP SERVERS THAT ARE ONLY USED IN THIS CAPACITY. Which means you already bought one too many.

Comment: It is possible, unless it is an OEM license. In that case it is linked to the original hardware. May need to be reactivated but it does work, otherwise no-one would be able to perform an offsite disaster recovery.